# List all modification times of a file

Tags: files

There are several methods to find the last modification time of a file. But is there a way to find *all* modification times of a file?

Answer (score 5):

No, you need software for this (and ofcourse it will not work on files changes before this is working). [Linux audit framework](https://goteleport.com/blog/linux-audit/) is the one to use.

> Linux Audit Framework, also known as auditd, was created to address the above problem. Linux Audit Framework allows a system administrator to log different system events and use them for post-mortem analysis. You can think about it like a "black box" on an airplane. Event logs often contain helpful information like executed commands, system calls, file access information and network statistics.

[auditd](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lunar/en/man8/auditd.8.html):

> `auditd`  is  the  userspace  component  to  the Linux Auditing System. It's responsible for
> writing audit records to the disk. Viewing the logs is done with the `ausearch` or  `aureport`
> utilities.  Configuring  the  audit  system  or  loading  rules  is done with the `auditctl`
> utility. During startup, the rules in `/etc/audit/audit.rules`  are  read  by  `auditctl`  and
> loaded  into the kernel. Alternately, there is also an augenrules program that reads rules
> located in `/etc/audit/rules.d/` and compiles them  into  an  audit.rules  file.  The  audit
> daemon  itself  has  some configuration options that the admin may wish to customize. They
> are found in the `auditd.conf` file.

Installation:

```
sudo apt-get install auditd
```

and edit `/etc/audit/auditd.conf` to your liking.

```
sudo auditctl -l
```

to create rules (this will alter `/etc/audit/rules.d/audit.rules`). [auditctl](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lunar/en/man8/auditctl.8.html) (man page) explains how to use it. But the rules need to be in  to form of

```
auditctl -w /dir/file -p permissions -k key_name
```

Answer (score 1):

Read `man stat`. `stat` offers:

```
%x
Time of last access
%X
Time of last access as seconds since Epoch
%y
Time of last modification
%Y
Time of last modification as seconds since Epoch
%z
Time of last change
%Z
Time of last change as seconds since Epoch
```